# convert a string containig 28bits to a BigInteger array? java

Tags: java, arrays, biginteger

I'm just trying to do the encrypt algorithm (DES) in java. So the algorithm is say that must divide the key that containing 56 bits into two parts of 28bits.

I have just try this to store the first and second half:

```
String firstPart="", secondPart="";
for(int i=0; i<PC1.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<PC1.length-1; j++){
            if(i<PC1.length/2)
                firstPart+=PC56bit[i][j];
            else
                secondPart+=PC56bit[i][j];
        }
    }
```

Output:

> firstPart  = 1111000011001100101010101111
>
> secondPart = 0101010101100110011110001111

The next step of the algorithm is to shift these two Strings (firstPart, secondPart) individually 16 times (with different shifting). So I just want to store these two string into a BigInteger array or any other types of array that make the process of shifting easier.

I tried with BigInteger and it doesn't doing it in a right way:

```
BigInteger C[] = new BigInteger[17], D[] = new BigInteger[17];
    C[0] = new BigInteger(firstPart, 2);
    D[0] = new BigInteger(secondPart, 2);
```

Output:

> C[0] = 252496559
>
> D[0] = 89548687

I don't know if my way of using BigInteger is true or not!

Is there any solves to my code? Or my way is wrong and there is a better way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: You are correctly seeing the decimal form of the binary numbers you are inputting.  What are you expecting?

Comment: Why they are in decimal, I just want them to be stored as they are in binary!  @Teepeemm

Comment: @Sivar they're not in decimal; that's just how BigIntegers appear when they are printed.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou you mean that they are stored in the binary format in C[0] and D[0]? which means there is no need to convert that decimal which is printed to binary again?

Comment: How they're stored isn't the programmer's concern.  If you want to get a digit, then you can print the number to binary and get the digit from the string.